# If my DNS TTL is 1 hour, should I expect half of name servers to have the new entry after 30 minutes?

Tags: domain-name-system, dns-hosting

Above is a specific version of this question, but more generally: Is there any reason to expect that name servers do not refresh their DNS entries at steady rate that is basically randomly distributed?

Comment: I deal with moving services all the time by changing DNS. My experience any record, no matter how short the TTL, will be used for months to come. I always use HTTP proxies or iptables/router NAT rules to reroute traffic.

Comment: Unless you’re Google, most DNS servers won’t have your record cached at all, and so the TTL won’t matter for those servers.

Answer (score 0):

The general pratice is to configure TTL value of A record to 5 minute when we are about to modify this record beacuse TTL value  will reflect the changes in name servers , Top level domain servers and roots server about this change within mentioned TTL value time .

For example if TTL value is set to 30 minutes and then if you modify A record it will take approximately 30 minutes to reflect changes in name servers , top level domain servers and root servers to clear cache and add this modify record this will reflect issue in productively of application

Answer (score 0):

Which TTL?

**Nameservers**
as in the result of $(dig +short NS example.com)

Masters update immediately, Slave servers will check the refresh TTL in the SOA record that tells the slave servers when to check for new records, unless a slave notify is sent, not all nameservers use dns based slave update methods, for example some will use CI jobs or a central database or even ldap

**Recursive Resolvers**
Generally speaking will expire your dns record when the record's TTL is reached after the first query, so a 1 hour ttl when you setup your record and then did a test will have to wait 1 hour for the corrected dns records to show up.

Also a good read on these terms: https://ns1.com/resources/understanding-ttl-values-in-dns-records

Comment: "1 hour ttl when you setup your record and then did a test will have to wait 1 hour for the corrected dns records to show up" - This seems right and I don't mean to question it. My more pointed question is given n regional slave servers, would you expect them to reach the TTL simultaneously? Or over some regular pattern (e.g. one server every 5 minutes because their TTLs expire at different times)